# pythonの練習問題わからない

Tags: python

ファイルの中からsから始まる単語を抜き出して
何種類あるのか、全部で合計何個かを出力するプログラムの作り方がわかりません。
ヒントに辞書型を使えと書いてありますがわかりません。
誰か教えてほしいです

Comment: その質問内容だと学習の進め方に問題がありそうです。何かの講座・講義や学習素材に従っているのであれば、練習問題とはそれまでの学習内容を確認・適用・応用するためのものでしょうから、直前までの学習内容を見直すことで解くことが出来るはずです。そうした事前学習無しに問題集的なものを解いているのであれば、それは学習の進め方に問題があるのでは？ あるいは示された問題のキーワードから関連する内容を調べるという逆方向の進め方なのかもしれませんが、その場合は安易に質問サイトを頼るのではなく自分で検索する能力を身に着けるべきでしょう。

Comment: 「ファイル」とはどのような形式のものでしょうか？（おそらくテキストファイルかとは思いますが内容詳細含めて情報が不足しています）　質問者さんはそのファイルを読み込むことはできますか？そこからコードを書けないのであれば復習された方が良いでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

コメントで御指摘のように条件が曖昧なので御参考です。
「英文テキストファイルから空白文字を含まず最初と最後の文字が英数字の文字列を抽出し，'s'（小文字のみ）から始まるものを抜き出す」という条件での記述例と出力を示します。なお，代入式（`:=`）を使っていますので Python3.8 以降が必要です。

```
import re

ptn = re.compile(r'^\W+|\W+$')

with open('The_last_leaf.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = [w for s in f.read().split() if (w := ptn.sub('', s))]

s_words = [w for w in words if w[:1] == 's']

print(f"words starting with 's': {len(s_words)}")
print(f"types of above:          {len(set(s_words))}")
```

```
words starting with 's': 179
types of above:          93
```